# Can't add CSS Style in MVC forms

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm developed the **MVC Project**, I want to style My project, but its not working correctly; I can't style my forms. **From control, button and Input areas** how can I do it my project? I want to some help

My code

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstMidName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstMidName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstMidName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to use it?

Comment: Have you looked for an online tutorial?

Comment: please give me a tutorial link, its better ,Thanks :)

Comment: you could check out these http://speckyboy.com/2009/07/02/20-resources-and-tutorials-for-creative-forms-using-css/ http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/ http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add css in **many ways**. Best method is creating own css file and making it **Bundles**. Or you can place it in _Layout.cshtml head section:

```
 <style>
    .custom-class{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

Then using it is pretty simple:

```
<div class="form-group custom-class">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the following steps :

- Create your CSS file with styles rules you want to apply (you will easily find many tutorials for CSS file creation).
- Add the created CSS file in a StyleBundle. To do this, go to the "BundleConfig.cs" file, and add the following line (replace the bundle name and CSS file path by real values) :

  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/NameOfTheBundle").Include("~/Content/YourCssFile.css"));
- Add a reference to the created bundle into your cshtml file (between the < head > tags, on the top of the file) :

  @Styles.Render("~/NameOfTheBundle")

A bundle is a file generated from one or several CSS (or javascript) files, by the .NET framework. It allows grouping CSS rules in a single file, to avoid client recovering many CSS files on your server (saving client/server requests).

Let me know if my answer is not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help .